# RXJava Observable emit items when subscribe with Observer as anonymous type ONLY

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

When I create a new Observer as anonymous type It works Fine:

```
Observable<List<Post>> postsListObservable = mApplicationAPI.getPosts();

        postsListObservable.
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe( new Observer<List<Post>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.i("ZOKa", "onSubscribe: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Post> posts) {

                Log.i("ZOKa", "onNext: " + posts.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.i("ZOKa", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.i("ZOKa", "onComplete: ");

            }
        });
```

When I create the Observer as a Dynamic Type it doesn't emit data

```
Observable<List<Post>> postsListObservable = mApplicationAPI.getPosts();

    postsListObservable.
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Observer<List<Post>>  observer = new Observer<List<Post>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.i("ZOKa", "onSubscribe: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Post> posts) {

            Log.i("ZOKa", "onNext: " + posts.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i("ZOKa", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i("ZOKa", "onComplete: ");

        }
    };
    postsListObservable.subscribe(observer);
```

Logcat for the first code snippet:

> com.tripleService.basesetupfordi/I/ZOKa: onSubscribe:
>   com.tripleService.basesetupfordi/I/ZOKa: onNext: 100:
>   com.tripleService.basesetupfordi/I/ZOKa: onComplete:

Logcat for the second one:

> com.tripleService.basesetupfordi/I/ZOKa: onError: null

So, What is the diff in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Operators return new observables, but they don't modify the observable that they were called on. `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` in the second example has no impact on the `postsListObservable` and the `observer`.

Following should work:

```
Observable<List<Post>> postsListObservable = mApplicationAPI.getPosts();


    Observable<List<Post>> postsListObservable2 = postsListObservable.
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Observer<List<Post>>  observer = new Observer<List<Post>>() {
        ...
    };

    postsListObservable2.subscribe(observer);
```

or

```
Observable<List<Post>> postsListObservable = mApplicationAPI.getPosts();

    Observer<List<Post>>  observer = new Observer<List<Post>>() {
        ...
    };

    postsListObservable.
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);
```